# Weblogic - Upgrade version from 10.3.0 to 10.3.4

Tags: weblogic

I am currently working on Weblogic 10.3.0 and need to upgrade to 10.3.4 for project requirements. I tried running the 1 GB exe from oracle site for 10.3.4 but it always fails at the time of extraction with 'Status Code = 50'.

I am guessing this is because of the already existing WL server on my machine. Can somebody please suggest how to upgrade to 10.3.4 without having to uninstall my 10.3.0 version.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing it to a different directory, change the WebLogic home directory and then restart your domain(s) to confirm it works.